# Service Bus MessageSession accepted but Receive returns null

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

We use Azure service bus queue, and receive messages using the AcceptMessageSession (code below).

Accepting the MessageSession succeeds, but then when I call Receive on the MessageSession, null is returned.

This doesn't happen all the time, but rather after some time since the creation of the queue. I verified the queue isn't empty when this happens.
When I close the MessageSession I see my queue shorten (in the correct number of messages!) but I hadn't received my messages...

The code I use:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ReceiveBatch<T>(TimeSpan waitTime)
    {
        MessageSession sessionReceiver = null;
        IEnumerable<T> retval;

        QueueClient queueClient = GetQueueClient<T>();

        try
        {
            sessionReceiver = queueClient.AcceptMessageSession(waitTime);
            retval = ReceiveSessionMessages<T>(sessionReceiver);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sessionReceiver != null) sessionReceiver.Close();
        }

        return retval;
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> ReceiveSessionMessages<T>(MessageSession receiver)
    {
        receiver.PrefetchCount = 10;

        BrokeredMessage message;
        var retval = new List<T>();
        while ((message = receiver.Receive()) != null)
        {
             var item = message.GetBody<T>();
             if (!Equals(item, default(T))) retval.Add(item);
        }

        return retval;
    }
```

UPDATE:

I have a suspicion that while all the messages of some session have expired, the session itself remains and so it is accepted but no messages are received.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of items to consider here, you are using `PrefetchCount` to do implicit batching, instead you can use the `RecieveBatch` APIs for explicitly getting a set of messages. See code sample below.

```
private IEnumerable<T> ReceiveSessionMessages<T>(MessageSession receiver)
        {
            var retval = new List<T>();
            var messages = receiver.ReceiveBatch(10);
            foreach(BrokeredMessage message in messages)
            {
                var item = message.GetBody<T>();
                if (!Equals(item, default(T))) retval.Add(item);
            }

            return retval;
        }
```

Also in the case where you get a `MessageSession` but no messages can you elaborate if they may have expired? Are you setting a `TimeToLive` value or the messages get deadlettered after `MaxDeliveryCount` is reached.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, I've originally did use RecieveBatch which didn't work just the same (with our without the PrefetchCount set). The TTL isn't the problem, deadlettering is turned of and there's only one receiver..

Comment: Have you ensured that there is no error being thrown in the GetBody call etc.?